# I'm making a chatbot translated into Portuguese but when the bot will send the answer instead of returning the translation it returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, discord.js, chatbot

I'm making a chatbot and I'm trying to understand why it's returning [object Object], I'm trying to translate the answer o from en to pt.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.channel.name == "chatbot") /*name channel*/ {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    message.content = message.content.replace(/@(everyone)/gi, "everyone").replace(/@(here)/gi, "here");

    if (message.content.includes(`@`)) {
      return message.channel.send(`**❌ Please dont mention anyone**`);
    }

    message.channel.startTyping();
    if (!message.content) return

    const translate = require("@iamtraction/google-translate"); //api

    const translated = await translate(message.content, {
      to: 'en'
    }); //translating

    /*message.channel.send("Please say something.");*/
    fetch(`https://api.affiliateplus.xyz/api/chatbot?message=${encodeURIComponent(translated)}&botname=${client.user.username}&ownername=DEVELOPER_NAME`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(async data => {
        const translat = await translate(data.message, {
          to: 'pt'
        }); //translating
        message.inlineReply(`${translat}`); //here is where it returns [object Object]
      });
    message.channel.stopTyping();
  }
});
```

Comment: I would expect: `if (message.content.includes(\`@\`)) { message.channel.send(\`**❌ Please dont mention anyone**\`); return; }`

Comment: is this part that is returning [object Object]: ```.then(async data => {
        const translat = await translate(data.message, {
          to: 'pt'
        }); //translating
        message.inlineReply(`${translat}`);```

Comment: ```[object Object]``` means when you try to concatenate string + object

Comment: `message.inlineReply(\`${translat}\`);` should be `message.inlineReply(translat);` but that is not a string so use `message.inlineReply(translat.text);` - there is rarely if ever a reason to use template literals on data you do not need to change before showing

Answer (score 0):

Based on the packages documentation in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iamtraction/google-translate) the translate method returns `Promise<Object>` with text property. It means that if you want to get the text after translation then you must use it as: `translat.text`